# Как ускорить взаимодействие Docker-а с системой? (Windows)

Tags: php, docker

Привык всю разработку веб-приложений вести через Docker, просто потому что так удобнее. На приложениях небольших всё отлично - сервер летает. Но вот сначала начал вести разработку на Wordpress, затем, на Laravel, в обоих случаях ожидания от взаимодействия с сервером 3-5 секунд, это очень долго! Нашёл инфу, что это вероятнее всего из-за монтирования корневой директории.
В качестве решения предлагают переходить на линукс -_-
"Docker не очень дружит с Windows файловой системой"

Есть ли какие-то менее радикальные решения, чтобы хоть как-то ускорить взаимодействие докера с системой, при этом не лишаясь преимуществ volumes-ов?

Comment: вы сначала проверьте, что проблема в том самом.

Comment: Надо не "вероятнее всего", а по-человечески профилирование провести, что конкретно и где конкретно жрёт время

Comment: у меня вот докер иногда тупит после выхода винды из спячки. vmem процессор  сжирает, решается перезапуском wsl

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась всё же отключением технологии WSL 2 контейнеризации в докере. Учитывая, что issue всё ещё открыт на их гите с 2019 года, сомневаюсь, что в ближайшее время будет хоть какое-либо адекватное решение...